# MPTableViewAdPlacer, place ads to second section

Tags: ios, mopub

MoPub placing ads to tableView's only to the first section by default. Is there any way to place ads to only second section instead? I see a way to do this by defining indexPathes explicitly, but what if I want to use received pathes, but only for second section?

Comment: did you find an answer for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Ok, I emailed their support but no response and their documentation is terrible. I am going to make a switch to AdMob since their UITableview integration is much more flexible.

Comment: Plus I have also noticed that MoPub native ads on Tableviews absolutely kills the performance of the tableview.

Comment: you can convert your comment into answer